# How can I show the osrmTrip function on the map in the order of departure with Osrm in R?

Tags: r, google-maps, maps, tmap, osrm

I have dataframes of some regions with coordinates I have. I can find the optimum result with the osrmTrip function.
But I can't visualize it the way I want on the map.
For example, if there are 11 coordinates, I want to show the order on the map as 2,5,7,3,1,10,11,9,4,6.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(osrm)

locations <- data.frame(
  name = c("M00105_0002", "M00119_0001", "M00119_0002", "M00119_0003", "M00130_0004",
           "M00130_0006", "M00148_0001", "M00248_0001", "M01447_0001", "M02140_0001", "M03098_0001"),
  lon = c(32.821526, 32.5463552, 32.5589275, 32.5282198, 32.5514539, 32.5522953,
          32.8610193, 32.7551178, 32.858116, 32.8166263, 33.0162826),
  lat = c(39.902631, 39.9854187, 39.98136215, 39.9625109, 39.97770642,
          39.97837557, 39.90700821, 39.9097558, 39.872466, 39.89336961, 40.0808236)
)


travel_time <- osrmTable(loc = cbind(locations$lon, locations$lat))
travel_time$durations[1:11,1:11]


diag(travel_time$durations) <- NA

median(travel_time$durations, na.rm = TRUE)


trips <- osrmTrip(loc = locations[1:11, c("lon", "lat")], overview = "full")
trips
```

Example code

I found a code structure similar to what I wanted on github. But I want the map to appear in the background like the map I showed in this example. But don't try to connect google maps because i can't get api.

```
mytrip <- trips[[1]]$trip
# Display the trip
plot(st_geometry(mytrip), col = c("black", "grey"), lwd = 2)
plot(st_geometry(pharmacy[1:5, ]), cex = 1.5, pch = 21, add = TRUE)
text(st_coordinates(pharmacy[1:5,]), labels = row.names(pharmacy[1:5,]), 
     pos = 2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD58d.png)